# iPhone tracking distance in the background

Tags: iphone, ios4

I was wondering, before learning the whole iPhone development stack, whether it was possible to even write an application in iOS 4 that can sit in the background and tell the user when certain geo-location events have happened?
For example, tell a jogger once he has traveled 4 miles, but without having to have the application always open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible on iOS 4.x devices. (It's one of the selling points - see the "Background location" section within the [What's New in iOS4 blurb](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/whats-new.html).)

If you want to take a look behind the hood, checkout the [CLLocationManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager) and the "[Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)" section of the iOS Application Programming Guide.

Comment: @ihponer - No worries - hope you enjoy the language and framework if you decide to take the plunge. (I've personally found Objective-C curiously addictive.) :-)